# Отправка в бд c неправильной кодировкой

Tags: php, mysql

У меня проблема, в бд записываться неверная кодировка. mb_detect_encoding показывает, что я отправляю в бд строку UTF-8. На самом деле база считает что я отправил cp1252 и выдает вот такую строку:

```
Ïîñòàíîâëåíèå ÔÀÑ Óðàëüñêîãî îêðóãà îò 26.12.2013 ã. ¹ Ô09-13522/13 Êàäàñòðîâàÿ ñòîèìîñòü çåìåëüíîãî ó÷àñòêà ðàâíà ðûíî÷íîé è îïðåäåëåíà íà ìîìåíò âñòóïëåíèÿ â ñèëó ñóäåáíîãî ðåøåíèÿ
```

У самой базы кодировка UTF-8.

Если сделать echo отправляемых данных, то получим нормальный русский текст. (страница php без html).

Возможно проблема в том, что данные которые используются, я как раз получаю в кодировке cp1252 от моего парсера и перевожу их в utf 8:

```
$page_title = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $page_title);
```

Что можете посоветовать в решении проблемы?

Answer (score 2):

Искали ?
hashcode просто завален подобными вопросами.
Побуду вангой.

1. set name utf8; - после коннекта к базе - первым запросом.
2. изменить коллейшн полей на utf8_general_ci

Comment: mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES cp1251");
Заработало с этим, почему?

Comment: Наверное потому что у вас страници отдаются в cp1251